# (Python) The validation works but the variable saves the first input, not the corrected one

Tags: python, validation

Our professor asked us to make a number system converter. I am currently making the binary to decimal conversion. We were not allowed to use methods that would automatically convert to any number system.

```
def base2():
    validate_x = ('0','1')
    x = int(input('Allowed numbers are "0-1", Enter your whole number: '))
    y = str(x)
    val = set(y)
    s = {'0','1'}
    if s == val or val == {'0'} or val == {'1'}:
        pass
    else:
        base2()
    return y
```

The validation works as it is but whenever it outputs the answer, it shows that the first input was used with the computation instead of the corrected one.

The output is:

```
Allowed numbers are "0-1", Enter your whole number: 6
Allowed numbers are "0-1", Enter your whole number: 5
Allowed numbers are "0-1", Enter your whole number: 1
The decimal value of  6 . 0  is 6.0
```

Comment: Probably `return base2()` will do the trick. You really shouldn't be using recursion here, a loop is a much better tool for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are recursively calling `base2()`, so when the input is correct you just return and return and return until you reach the first time you called `base2()`, and then you return to the caller the number the user entered (in this case - 6).
Change your code so instead of a recursive call to `base2()`, you loop in a `while` loop until you are satisfied with the input:

```
def base2():
    validate_x = ('0','1')
    s = {'0','1'}
    x = int(input('Allowed numbers are "0-1", Enter your whole number: '))
    y = str(x)
    val = set(y)
    
    while not (s == val or val == {'0'} or val == {'1'}):
        x = int(input('Allowed numbers are "0-1", Enter your whole number: '))
        y = str(x)
        val = set(y)

    return y
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Ill learn more about recursive calling. Can I ask what the while not statement is comparing from?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. can you please rephrase it?